# It is possible to pass a parameter to Blazor Root Component?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

What I want is to do this:

```
<div id="app" test="hello">Loading...</div>
```

And capture the parameter value in the App root component

Comment: Not that I know of.  As `App` only gets loaded once on SPA startup, there are other ways to pass in configuration information.  What are you doing with `test` and where does it's value come from?

Comment: I'm trying to load blazor components to an external web page without using the blazor router, I thought to pass the name of the component and inside the App create a dynamic component with that value

Comment: Can you post more example code to show what you are trying to achieve?  What type of page is "External web page" and how is it rendering the components?

Comment: Finally I did a workaround with await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("getProperty", "app", "myproperty"); and a jsfunction that reads the property I want

Comment: That works.  I've suggested a similar approach a couple of times recently to access or change startup page data such as stylesheets.

Comment: may you post your solution?

Comment: @Gianpiero here is the javascript code and a complete example https://github.com/elgransan/BlazorWasmWithNetFrameworkMVC/blob/master/WebApplication5/Views/Shared/Blazor.cshtml